# Как сделать команду mine и farm

Tags: discord.py, discord-api

Здраствуйте всем как сделать команды для бота: «Комманда mine: разрешается только в одном канале, когда человек пишет её ему выводится «Вы добыли (тут рандомные слова «Камень, железо, изумруд , алмаз) вы получили ( и тут чтобы допустим если добыл камень то тебе пишут 1.000.000 денег ожидайте вам модератор выдаст деньги) . Прошу пожалуйста помочь тк я сегодня начал писать на питоне и дискорд ботов.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда-то делал такое:

```py
def main():
    count = 10
    item_chances = {
        'stone': 40000,
        'ruby': 5200,
        'sapphire': 5100,
        'ametist': 5000,
        'obsidian': 4200,
        'iron': 3200,
        'gold': 2700,
        'diamond': 1500,
        'uranium': 800,
    }
    selected = random.choices(list(item_chances.keys()), weights=list(item_chances.values()), k=count)
    items = []
    for item in set(selected):
        items.append((item, selected.count(item)))

    print(items)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

p.s. вставить в команду и сам сможешь)

Comment: Спасибо, а не подскажешь как сделать так «я пишу команду !add-money cash „человек» 100000 и человеку этому должна отправится в лс сообщение типо « вам выдано «тут надо получить деньги которое написал модер»

Comment: Отправил заявку в друзья